# Why does StreamingQueryStatus.isDataAvailable is turned on when no records are available in Kafka topic?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-kafka, spark-structured-streaming

I have to stop spark structured streaming query. So first, I check the status is there any data available in Kafka to process. if yes, processes it and then stop the query.

```scala
if (query.status.isDataAvailable) {
                    query.processAllAvailable()
                  }
query.stop()
```

After Jacek Laskowski's suggestion, I have modified the implementation.
I have list of streaming queries,

```scala
streamingQueryList.foreach{query =>
query.stop()
}
```

After every stopping of query, it throws following exception:

```
java.lang.InterruptedException
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.doAcquireSharedInterruptibly(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:998)
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.acquireSharedInterruptibly(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:1304)
    at scala.concurrent.impl.Promise$DefaultPromise.tryAwait(Promise.scala:202)
    at scala.concurrent.impl.Promise$DefaultPromise.ready(Promise.scala:218)
    at scala.concurrent.impl.Promise$DefaultPromise.ready(Promise.scala:153)
    at org.apache.spark.util.ThreadUtils$.awaitReady(ThreadUtils.scala:222)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.runJob(DAGScheduler.scala:621)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2022)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$$anonfun$write$1.apply$mcV$sp(FileFormatWriter.scala:179)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$$anonfun$write$1.apply(FileFormatWriter.scala:164)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$$anonfun$write$1.apply(FileFormatWriter.scala:164)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withNewExecutionId(SQLExecution.scala:65)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$.write(FileFormatWriter.scala:164)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.FileStreamSink.addBatch(FileStreamSink.scala:123)
    at org.apache.spark.
```

For debugging purpose, I have printed the `recentProgress` of query to know the current topic from where spark is reading. And I have checked the topic using console consumer and there is no data in Kafka and but `query.status.isDataAvailable` prints true. And even if recentProgress is empty, it is still waiting for data to process. Due to which it is infinitely waiting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure why `isDataAvailable` gives `true`, but `processAllAvailable` gives you exactly the solution you're aiming at with `if (query.status.isDataAvailable)` block.

> **processAllAvailable** Blocks until all available data in the source has been processed and committed to the sink.

That's your use case, *isn't it?*

Mind however that *"This method is intended for testing."* as *"this method may block forever"* (quoting the scaladoc of [processAllAvailable](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.sql.streaming.StreamingQuery@processAllAvailable():Unit)).

You should use [awaitTermination](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.sql.streaming.StreamingQuery@awaitTermination():Unit) instead to keep the main thread blocked (so your streaming application is up and running) and `stop` the query (and its background thread) at your convenience from another "monitoring" thread.

> **awaitTermination()** Waits for the termination of this query, either by `query.stop()` or by an exception. If the query has terminated with an exception, then the exception will be thrown.

Comment: Thanks for response. I have used processAllAvailable in main code. Basically in my use case, spark is reading the data from kafka and writing it to S3. And in middle of that there comes a call of stopping the running stream query. So first i have to ensure that all available data has been written to S3. That's Why i have used this code snippet. If there is better approach to achieve same. Please enlighten me. And how can i do that with using queryAwaitTermination?

Comment: You cannot know whether there's data to be processed or not. Spark won't give you the information as there's this delay between Spark knows there's data to be processed and when it's really processed. Spark knows that there's data for processing when the trigger to process the data has been started. That's why I think `stop` should be enough as it will allow for stopping the query right after the current trigger has finished so all the data that Spark knows about has already been processed.

Comment: Thanks Jacek, i have tried it. Now it is work but as i did query.stop. It threw java.lang.InterruptedException. If it is waiting for process to complete why it is throwing this error?

Comment: And are you sure that spark will process all available data before stopping the streaming query?

Comment: I'm sure, but not so sure after having read about your use case :) In other words, it *ought* to work fine. I think InterruptedException is to "announce" that you interrupted the thread that's been waiting for the background thread to finish. Can you show how you stop and what the exception is (edit your question)?

Comment: It worked. Now we are using query.awaitTermination. It is working fine. Thanks!